# I need help deleting a newly inserted row

Tags: mysql

The row that I inserted was:

```
insert into planes (Tailnum, year, type, manufacturer, model, engines, seats, speed, engine)
Values ('N15501','2013','fixed wing single engine', 'BOEING', 'A222-01', '3', '100', NULL, 'TURBO-FAN');
```

I need to delete the row after I inserted.

Comment: you have and unique identifier for this row?

Comment: Does your table have unique ID's?

Comment: If not, I am sure you could select 3 or 4 columns and combined, it would be unique. `DELETE FROM PLANES WHERE Tailnum = 'N15501' AND year = '2013' AND manufacturer = 'BOEING' and engines = 'A222-01';`  If so you could `DELETE TOP 1 FROM PLANES ORDER BY ID DESC`

Answer (score 0):

assuming that Tailnum is an unique identifier  for this row in your table

you can use delete

```
delete from planes
where Tailnum  ='N15501';
```